# xml.dom.minidom getting elements by tagname

Tags: python, xml, minidom

How can I retrieve the value of **code** with this (below) xml string and when using xml.dom.minidom?

```
<data>
    <element1>
        <name>myname</name>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <code>3</code>
        <name>another name</name>
    </element2>
</data>
```

Because multiple 'name' tags can appear I would like to do something like this:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
dom = parseString("<data>...</data>")
dom.getElementsByTagName("element1").getElementsByTagName("name")
```

But that doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Arg... I found a stupid mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code worked fine for me. I think you had multiple  tags and you want to get the name from the second tag.

```
myxml = """\
<data>
    <element>
        <name>myname</name>
    </element>
    <element>
        <code>3</code>
        <name>another name</name>
    </element>
</data>
"""

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(myxml)
nodelist = dom.getElementsByTagName("element")[1].getElementsByTagName("name")
for node in nodelist:
    print node.toxml()
```

Comment: dom.getElementsByTagName("element1")[0].getElementsByTagName("name") is essential (the [0])